# Android: How to find out if keyboard/soft input is visible using a background service

Tags: android

It is possible to determine if the keyboard is visible from an activity but is it possible to determine from a background service? I'm developing a floating action button feature that's pinned to the bottom, however, when the keyboard comes up I want to re-position the floating action button.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually not even possible to do from an Activity.  There's some code that's widely distributed that tries to do it, but its based on a hack that may or may not work under all circumstances.  I wouldn't rely on it.  Particularly it has problems with split screen mode, alternative keyboards with very small heights, and when screen casting to different size monitors. Under all those circumstances it has a tendency to break.  It may work some of the time, but its not reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a way we can bind to the current InputMethodService?